# Is there a way to paint on a JPanel object from ouside it's class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I searched and found a few questions worded similar, but nothing that applied to my situation so here I go.

I'm trying to make a game with different levels, each level plays completely different.

originally, my code looked like this and worked fine:

```
public class Life extends JPanel{

private Story story;

public Life(){
    story = new Story(this);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    story.render(g)

public void terminate(){
    story.terminate();
    System.out.println("Terminated");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Life");
    final Life life = new Life();
    frame.add(life);
}
}



public class Story {

private int phase;
private Life life;


public Story(Life life){
    this.life = life;
    phase = 0;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    if(phase == 0) levelOneRender(g);
    if(phase == 1) levelTwoRender(g);
}
}
```

I was worried that I'd be wasting time every game tick checking what phase I was in. Since I plan to have 20+ phases, the code would get inefficient fast.

So I had an idea to simply pass along the Graphics object from JPanel from my Life object to my Story Object and paint the Jpanel in a different class for each phase like this:

```
public class Life extends JPanel{

public Life(){

    story = new Story(this);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Life");
    final Life life = new Life();

}

}


public class Story {

private int phase;
private Intro intro;
private Life life;


public Story(Life life){
    this.life = life;
    phase = 0;
    intro = new Intro(this);
}

public void nextPhase(){
    this.phase++;
}


public Life getLife() {
    return this.life;
}
}

public class Intro {

private static final int DELAY = 100; // in milliseconds, so 10 ticks per second

private Timer timer;
private Story story;
private Graphics g;
private int counter;


public Intro(Story story) {
    this.story = story;
    this.g = story.getLife().getGraphics();
    this.counter = 0;

    timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tick();
            story.repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

public void tick(){
    if(counter <= 40){
        terminate();
    }
    counter++;
    render();
}

public void render(){
    story.getLife().paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2.draw(new Rectangle(0,0,10,10));


}

public void terminate(){
    timer.stop();
    story.nextPhase();
}
}
```

Unfortunately this just doesnt work, as story.getLife().paint(g); in class Intro throws a nullPointerException, when I run it. And I'm quite sure that's not the only problem with my attempt at this.

Is there a correct way to do what I'm going for?

Thank you very much for your time. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You could create another class that has a `paint(Graphics g)` method, then call that within the paintComponent method of the panel (the one you override in the class that extends `JPanel`): `myPainter.paint(g);`. You can then handle the painting in the new class you created

Comment: originally I used paintComponent, but it's a protected method, so I couldn't reference it. paint is public, and seemed similar enough so I tried it, and failed lol. That's not a bad idea, it would fix the error, but how is it different from my first code?

Comment: You aren't supposed to call `paint` or `paintComponent` yourself. The Swing rendering system calls them. As for the difference, there is none. Didn't even see that tbh :s But your problem is an easy fix. Create `Level` objects, then have a `Level level;` field variable. Switch it's value to switch levels. I'll post an answer

Comment: First of all, you should NEVER need to call `paint` yourself, this method is the entry point for the paint subsystem.  Next, you view or component should be painting it's own current state, probably coming from some kind of model or other data/manager class.  You main loop should interact with this model/manager, telling to update what ever it needs to update and the repainting the the current view.  This is essentially a concept of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    if(phase == 0) levelOneRender(g);
    if(phase == 1) levelTwoRender(g);
}
```

This is not as big of a problem as you think. What you have now is fine. But those checks can be avoided (as you are requesting).

Rather than handle the painting for each level in separate methods, handle them in separate objects:

```
public bstract class Level {
    public abstract void paint(Graphics g);
}

public final class LevelOne extends Level {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //...
    }
}

public final class LevelTwo extends Level {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This way, instead of checking an `int` value to see which render to draw, you can just switch a `Level` value to render a new level:

```
Level one = new LevelOne();
Level two = new LevelTwo();

Level currentLevel = one;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    currentLevel.paint(g);
}
```

Simply switch the value of `level` to render different levels

Comment: Thanks for the insight, what I've tried to do instead is make Story extend JFrame, and each individual level class extend JPanel, and add and remove the panels from the frame.

Comment: Story [is not a](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `JFrame` (as in `Dog` is an `Animal`), so it should not extend it. And rather than add/remove, you'd wanna use `CardLayout` to switch between panels. Although a `Level` is not a `JPanel` either (a `JPanel` is simply a drawing area/component container). Your `Level` could [have a](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) `LevelPanel`. Maybe have a `LevelContainer` (controller) that has a `Level` (model) and a `LevelPanel` (view). Check out MadProgrammer's comment for more info

Comment: hmm, you make an excellent point. okay I will fix to agree with these ideas.

Comment: @KingTheoden A quick suggestion: feel free to post it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) (it must be working) to get it reviewed for more suggestions :)